# LTspice and op-amp strange behavior

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I noticed a strange behavior using TL074 and I made this simplified block to verify my feeling. Opposite to what I see on a breadboard, I think the output(s) are totally wrong, but I cannot believe a so dramatic result, so I assume I am terribly wrong somewhere.

On the breadboard, I have a double supply for +15 and -15 V as well as a 10K pot between the rails, so it can feed -15 to +15V to the inputs. With the exclusion of a very little range near 0V where I see intermediate, the output of the **real** TL074 is banging to +13 or -13V, depending on the differential between the two inputs and I assume that is the correct behavior of a dual rail op-amp.

Of course, in LTspice I also replaced the TL074 with some other dual rail OP Amps with almost the same result.
Regarding the included image, the green plot is the output of V3, the violet one is U1/4 and the red  is U2/4.

Where am I wrong?
Thanks!

[image: LTspice simulation]

Comment: Are you using opamp as "comparators" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're powering the op-amp from 0V. Run a DC analysis and check the voltages on the power pins :)

Comment: Good catch! :-)

Answer (score 5):

V1 should be "+15V" in order to have -15V as a negative supply rail. Or you can have V1 at "-15V" and turn the voltage generator 180°. Post your graph when done

Comment: Yes, you are right. I noticed and fixed it but no substantial change.

Answer (score 3):

You have added wire labels (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and, in the process, more than one net share the same label. The effect is you are shorting out those nets. Either delete the labels, or use unique names for each net. Also, what [@Arthur Chassande](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/617415/95619) says about the supply is true. And you should always check that the models are correct before using them in a simulation (test them). One often found case is that the pins order is not the same as the symbol's (the symbol has `-`, `+`, `Vcc`, `Vee`, `out`, usually -- but it's not the law).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your pin numbers are wrong and your sim program might not have a model of a TL074.

[image: TL074]

Comment: Yes, TL074 is a quad OPAmp and have very different pins. Thai said, I follwed instructions to add TL084 to LTspice library and that is what I get. I found that LT1358 is almost the same. I replaced TL084 with it (once fixed the supply voltage) and yes, I have a new behavior, but still not as expected.  The output of U1 is what I guessed, but the output of U2 is always +13V. That said, now I have TWO problems: the model of TL084 I used is wrong and I still have something unexpected!

Comment: Basic rule for operation of an opamp as linear amplifier: Negative feedback. This requirement can be found in each text dealing with opamps.

Comment: The pin order as displayed in the datasheet has nothing to do with the way they are, or should be listed inside a `.subckt`.

Answer (score 1):

After many and many models tested, I finally found ***UniversalOpAmp3*** that works exactly as I see with the real TL074 on a breadboard and, as far as I understood, an OP amp should work. At this point I wonder if the models I found before are all wrong or I am terribly misunderstanding something!
[image]

Comment: Could you please explain why are you still powering U2 with +14V and 0V, while applying +-10V to its input?

Comment: As @a concerned citizen pointed out, labels interconnect the same "point" name. So, it is not your model that was wrong, but your original schematic ... :-)

Comment: @Antonio51 Well, I know, you know, but OP surely has a strange way of selecting answers. :-) Can't say it's because OP is new to the site, seems to be more than a year since joining.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated this, as usual, nothing strange.
With [microcap12](https://www.spectrum-soft.com)
As already stated, check your model. Update: and your original schematic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Works fine the TL071 model (which is just 1/4 of the TL074 model). Maybe there is an error in your model if you have fixed the power supply and it still doesn't work. Or maybe you did a double reversal on the power supply and nothing changed?

[image]

Comment: Yes, with THIS very schematic and Tl071 model, I have the same behavior. But If I connect the (-) input to 0V and the (+) input to vIn, (see 2nd OP amp in my schematic), I expect a reverse output, but I don't. With the real OP amp on a breadboard, I have the reverse square wave.

Comment: @Resca The second opamp in your schematic is not connected to the negative power rail, so it is expected that its output doesn't go below 0V.